# Present a UITabBarController at a specific index

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I would like to present a `UITabBarController` at a specific index. What I have:

```
let mainTabController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainTabBarController")
self.presentViewController(mainTabController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have tried placing the index selection in the completion handler of `presentViewController`, but that didn't work

I also tried downcasting `mainTabController` to `UITabBarController` but that didn't allow me, leading me to believe that this is not the right method to achieve my goal.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at the `UITabBarControllerDelegate`, it should have a proper method you can use for this. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/

Comment: @dfri you misunderstood. I am not trying to present a specific index of `UITabBarController`. I am trying to present a `UITabBarController`, at a specific index.

Comment: sorry, I don't think I follow, but maybe someone else can help, gotta sleep now!

Comment: do you have MainTabBarController swift class? if so add as! MainTabBarController. it worked for me

Comment: @AlokSubedi Ya that's the answer, and then i put `selectedIndex` before presenting it